# Combine multiple row into single row if index are sequentially

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lowercase

It,s look like i want to convert multiple row to single row in animal column. But, it only conditional if they met sequential number and lowercase alphabet. after that, it restart an index to become sequent

So, i have a dataframe like :

```
    Animal 
 0  Bulldog
 1  hatcet 
 3  Parrot 
 7  Carrot 
 8  Jack Dog
 9  Kanggaroo
 10 helma
```

Thing i want to achieve is

```
    Animal 
 0  Bulldog hatcet 
 1  Parrot
 2  Carrot 
 3  Jack Dog
 4  Kanggaroo helma
```

Anyone can pass this?

Comment: You define sequential using index value or just the position? Suppose `Parrot` is lowercase `parrot`, will it get concatenated with `Bulldog hatcet` or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can identify the sequential blocks by first creating a boolean mask using `str.contains` then taking cumulative sum on the mask. then group the column `Animal` on these sequential blocks and aggregate using `join`

```
b = df['Animal'].str.contains(r'^[A-Z]').cumsum()
df[['Animal']].groupby(b, as_index=False).agg(' '.join)
```

---

```
            Animal
0   Bulldog hatcet
1           Parrot
2           Carrot
3         Jack Dog
4  Kanggaroo helma
```